# @PostConstruct dont call in a session managed bean

Tags: java, jsf-2, scope, richfaces, managed-bean

Like I say in the title, I have a method with the `@PostConstruct` tag in a managed bean in session scope. But the method is never called. In another bean in view scope the `@PostConstruct` works fine.
The `@Postconstruct` tag work in a session bean?
That's basically my question.
Bye and thanks!

Comment: I think OP is talking abt JSF

Comment: Hi, Im using JSF 2.0 with Richfaces 4

Comment: Are you sure the method is not being called? How?

Comment: @PostConstruct
public void init(){  
System.out.println("PostConstruct - series");
  } the PostConstruct - series is never show

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you don't have a @PostConstruct on any other method in your bean or your bean's predecessor.
There is **only one @PostConstruct allowed** for a managed bean.

Comment: Perhaps you could add a link to the docs where this info can be found

Comment: "Only one method in the bean class can be annotated with this annotation. If you annotate more than one method with this annotations, the EJB will not deploy."
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/ejb30/annotations.html#wp1424850

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue. The issue get resolved when I destroy the bean from the session(if the bean is in the session scope, it works fine for request scope). 
When the bean is in the session scope, the method with the  @PostConstruct annotation will never be called twice, as the bean has already been instantiated and is stored in the session.

Answer (score 0):

How do you refer the session bean? Maybe the bean was not instantiated yet, do you also have some logging in the constructor of the managed bean?

Comment: Sorry, I refer to the scope of the bean.

Comment: Also, the constructor is never called, but the bean work just fine, except the @postconstruct method and constructor not called

Answer (score 0):

> *Also, the constructor is never called, but the bean work just fine, except the @postconstruct method and constructor not called*

Either you have not compiled and deployed the bean class with the changes, or you have another copy of the bean with the same name but in a different package which in turn is actually been used instead.

Verify everything, cleanup everything and do a full rebuild/redeploy/restart.